# jQuery blur not working

Tags: jquery, textinput, onblur

jQuery's `blur()` function refuses to work. Although the input value gets saved, it doesn't show. Can anyone tell me why? I've also tried `on('blur', function(){});` with no luck.

```
$('form').each(function() {
    $(this).find(':input')
        .not('input[type=submit], input[type=hidden]')
        .each(function() {

        if (!($.trim($(this).val()))) {
            if ($(this).attr('data-placeholder')) {
                putPlaceholder(this);
            }
        }
        $(this).blur(function() {
            if (!($.trim($(this).val()))) {
                putPlaceholder(this);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: blur is triggering correctly http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/aswXV/

Comment: Are you looking to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cMSEJ/2/

Comment: hey thanks but it doesn't work when i run it from a remote server. been trying to debug with no luck. was wondering if i could write it another way

Answer (score 0):

I got it working perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmmshuddup/aswXV/3/

```
var placeholder = "I'm a placeholder";
function putPlaceholder(el) {
    // do something
    el.value = placeholder;
    $(el).addClass('placeholder');
}

$('form').each(function() {
    $(this).find(':input')
        .not('input[type=submit], input[type=hidden]')
        .each(function() {
        if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
            if ($(this).attr('data-placeholder')) {
                putPlaceholder(this);
            }
        }

        $(this).focus(function() {
            if (this.value == placeholder) {
                this.value = '';
            }
            $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
        }).blur(function() {
            if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
                putPlaceholder(this);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i've already tried it there myself too, and it worked. it doesn't work when i run it from a remote server. i was wondering if thers any other way i could write it because i am really out of ideas.

Comment: install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in your browser and tell me what errors you get.

Comment: speaking of which, in _which_ browser(s) is this happening?  everything else works except the `onblur` event listener? etc etc

Comment: thats part of the problem..I do not get any errors! the value gets set the first time putPlaceholder is called. when its called on blur, the value gets set (it says so in the source code) but just doesnt show. its the same on firefox and chrome. i need it only for android browser anyways

Comment: and by just doesn't show i mean the input field remains blank.

Comment: also i am using the keydown event to reset the value to blank (and not the focus event). it doesnt work with or without the keydown event anyways.

Comment: It doesn't show? Can you _select_ it? Who knows..I mean maybe your text is white or something? :S

Comment: yup..the field remains blank. i can select the input field but there is nothing in there. and nop, the color is grey.

Comment: i know, there isn't much here, and ive given up on fixing it, but is there any other way to write this?